# Building an effective js/ jQ 'thousands' comma separator that works for large numbers (10^6+) on key up

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have spent time looking through each of the proposed solutions to the problem of adjusting user input strings as they type to format a large number to have comma separators:

9999999999 --> 9,999,999,999 and so on.

There are several discussions here on stack overflow:

[How to print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript)

[Adding comma as thousands separator (javascript) - output being deleted instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621769/adding-comma-as-thousands-separator-javascript-output-being-deleted-instead)

and many more related queries, I've tested those that I could find, and they worked well for numbers up to a power of 4 or 5, eg 12,345 comes out nicely,

But larger numbers end up with far too many commas:

1,,,,,0,,,0,,,000

for example is the output of the code I currently have implemented. (It also registers backspace as a key stroke, so when I backspace three times it adds a comma...)

```
function numberWithCommas(n){
    var s=n.split('.')[1];
    (s) ? s="."+s : s="";
    n=n.split('.')[0]
    while(n.length>3){
        s=","+n.substr(n.length-3,3)+s;
        n=n.substr(0,n.length-3)
    }
    return n+s
}
```

and then on the input:

```
onkeyup="this.value=numberWithCommas(this.value);"
```

Am I using the function incorrectly? Or is it simply not viable for larger numbers. Is there a way it can be adjusted to work for any size of number?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just for fun, you can use a regex to do it: https://tinker.io/5cc23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just adding comas to a value which already as commas after the first iteration... You should just reset the commas at the beginning of your function `numberWithCommas`:

```
n = n.replace(/,/g, "");
```

Comment: So simple, so many hours of me trying to figure this out >_< one day I will understand enough to not have to beat my face against a problem for so long :) Thanks very much - works perfectly.