# Removing commas in 'live' input fields in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, number-formatting

I have a series of input boxes in a table with some number of dynamically generated rows as such:

```
<table id="someDataTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td >Some Title</td>
            <td >Units</td>
            <td >Val/Unit</td>
            <td >Value</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" size="30" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" size="14" class="units commas"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" size="14" class="value commas"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" size="14" readonly="readonly" class="autoTotal"/></td>
        </tr>
...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now, I have a blur() call to add commas every time an input box is exited to add commas with the nifty [Number Formatter](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-numberformatter/) plugin, and it simply does this:

```
<script>
$(".commas").blur(function () {
     $(this).parseNumber({ format: "#,###", locale: "us" });
     $(this).formatNumber({ format: "#,###", locale: "us" });
});
</script>
```

And it works beautifully.  Now, on the other side, I also have a chunk of code that does the form math automatically on every keystroke.  It has a call in initialize() that looks like this:

```
 $(document).on('keyup', '#someDataTable', DoCalculations);
```

The function it invokes looks like this:

```
function DoCalculations() {
    $(this).find('tr').each(function () {
        var tUnits = $(this).find('.units').val();
        var tValue = $(this).find('.value').val();
        $(this).find('.autoTotal').val(Math.round(tUnits * tValue));
    });
}
```

--

Now, my problem:  I need to be able to rip out the commas to do the calculations.  I was hoping to be able to use NumberFormatter's parseNumber() function to do this, but it was having a small fit.  This was the alternate code in DoCalculations to attempt to accomplish that:

```
function DoCalculations() {

    $(this).find('tr').each(function () {

        var tTotal;
        var tUnits = $(this).find('.units').val();
        var tValue = $(this).find('.value').val();

        tUnits = $.parseNumber(tUnits, { format: "#,###", locale: "us" });
        tValue = $.parseNumber(tValue, { format: "#,###", locale: "us" });

        tTotal = tUnits * tValue;
        tTotal = $.formatNumber(tTotal, { format: "#,###", locale: "us" });

        $(this).find('.autoTotal').val(tTotal);
    });
}
```

But it comes back with a runtime error in NumberFormatter.js, where it cannot get the property of numberString.indexOf of undefined or null reference.  Line 442 to be exact.  I'm not sure why though.  I originally thought it was because there were empty input boxes, but that turned out to not matter.

At the end of the day, I need to strip out commas.

Comment: parseFloat(tUnits.replace(/,/g,""));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing characters is something that regular expressions excel at:

```
var tValue = parseFloat($(this).find('.value').val().replace(/,/g, ''));
```

**UPDATE**

If `val()` can be null/undefined, you can add a check like this:

```
var tValue = $(this).find('.value').val();
tValue = tValue ? parseFloat(tValue.replace(/,/g, '')) : 0;
```

Comment: That actually works brilliantly...except that the code throws ye olde' 'Unable to get property 'replace' of undefined or null reference.'  The thing is if I just Ignore all the errors, it ends up working.  My guess is that I've screwed something else up in between all of this.  Thoughts?

Comment: Maybe `val()` is not returning a string. I guess you could do a check for that beforehand. Adding update.

Comment: The update cleared it all up!  Many thanks to you sir, you've saved me a lot of time!