# Convert a JavaScript number to a currency format, but without "$" or any currency symbol

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to convert my JavaScript number into a currency number, but with any currency symbol

Suppose this is my number:

```
var number = 43434;
```

The result should be like this:

```
43,434
```

And not this:

```
$43,434
```

Comment: Please show us what you've tried, how its not working, etc.  This site isn't some place where you get people to do your work for you; if you expect time and effort to be put into answers, you have to put time and effort into your question.

Comment: Supporting @Daedalus and agree with Alex link, its awesome one.

Comment: There are plenty of similar questions. You can find how to do it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript and there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621769/adding-comma-as-thousands-separator-javascript-output-being-deleted-instead

Comment: One way is to use D3 library , see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51423760/7848529)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Using one regex `/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g`:

```
"1234255364".replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
"1,234,255,364"
```

To achieve this with an integer you can use `+""` trick:

```
var number = 43434;
(number + "").replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,"); // 43,434
```

Comment: If anyone is getting ".replace is not defined" error trying to use it on a number then apply toString() before using replace, e.g. $number.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")